# FullScreen Webview video android

Tags: android, video, webview

I am aware of other people asking webView questions.  My problem is that I want my video to distort to fit the screen.  The problem that I have is the video maintains its aspect ratio, thus being too big or too small for the screen.  I want my video just to fit to the edge of the screen.

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setInitialScale(getScale());
webView.loadUrl(getConnectionUrl());
//set the layout width
getScreenDimensions();

//set webview orientation
webView.getLayoutParams().height = (int)mHeight;
webView.getLayoutParams().width = (int)mWidth;
```

Comment: Videos in a webview are a bad idea.

Comment: Is there an alternative that I can use,  The problem is I need to load images and videos from a webpage.

Comment: That should be no issue. Depending on your view/library you just need to enter the right url.

Comment: @rekire  The video loads fine, the issue is the scaling it to fit the screen.  Currently the video won't lose it's aspect ratio, and I need it to be able to distort itself to fit the screen.

Comment: To be honest I never used the WebView (except as part of admob), so I don't know it.